# Wordpress dynamic_sidebar in header blocks the rendering of the rest of the theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm having this weird issue using a `dynamic_sidebar` in my header.php.  I have created a sidebar to be used in my header so I can display the search widget next to my nav. What's weird is that when I render the `dynamic_sidebar` in the header.php, the rest of the site stops rendering. Meaning it doesn't render anything else after the `get_header` function but I am able to see the correct sidebar in the header.  when I remove just that dynamic_sidebar, the site renders normally again

edit:  I'm on WordPress 4.7.5 because my client is on the same one and I don't have access to update theirs.  I'm working on getting them to upgrade

**index.php**

```
<?php get_header();?>
  <div id="content" role="main">
    <?php get_template_part( 'inc/my-template-part', 'default' ); ?>
  </div><!-- #content -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**header.php**

```
<header class="clearfix">
  <div class="header-inner">
    <h1 class="site-title logo">
      <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" 
        title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" 
        rel="home">
        <img class="w-100 db"
          src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/logo.png" 
          alt="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>">
      </a>
    </h1>

    <nav class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
      <?php 
        wp_nav_menu( array(
            'theme_location' => 'primary', 
            'items_wrap' => '<ul class="menu-ul lst-n">%3$s</ul>'
          )); 
      ?>
    </nav>

    <!-- if I remove this part it works normally again -->
    <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-nav-search' ) ) : ?>
      <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-nav-search' ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

  </div>
</header>
```

**functions.php**

```
function my_widgets_init() {

  register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => __( 'Nav Search', 'my-theme-v2' ),
    'id' => 'sidebar-nav-search',
    'description' => __( 'Appears in the top main navigation at the far right', 'my-theme-v2' ),
    'before_widget' => '',
    'after_widget' => '',
    'before_title' => '',
    'after_title' => '',
  ) );

  register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => __( 'Footer', 'my-theme-v2' ),
    'id' => 'sidebar-footer',
    'description' => __( 'Appears in the footer of every page', 'my-theme-v2' ),
    'before_widget' => '',
    'after_widget' => '',
    'before_title' => '',
    'after_title' => '',
  ) );

}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'my_widgets_init' );
```

Comment: did you check the source code? does the output stops right before ```<div id="content" role="main">``` does it happened both when the widget has assign content or not?

Comment: in the source code it literally stops right after the search widget.  The last element rendered is the button to submit the search.  The widget also has a text widget int it.  When I remove the search widget, site renders fine, even with the text widget in there.  When I add back the search widget, the problem occurs again

Comment: so you mean if you remove the search widget from the sidebar, the site works fine? and if you add the search widget on the sidebar it will break? seems like the problem is the search widget form? did you try embedding ```get_search_form``` directly and see what happens?

Comment: can you try replacing ```<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-nav-search' ) ) : ?><?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-nav-search' ); ?><?php endif; ?>``` with ```<?php get_search_form(); ?>```

Comment: @silver same exact issue using `get_search_form()` directly.  so weird!

Comment: then the problem is ```get_search_form()``` and not the sidebar, did you create ```searchform.php``` as part of your theme or you rely on the native wordpress form? you better use a plain html as your search form e.g. ```<form action="/" method="GET"> <input type="text" name="s"><input type="submit" value="Search"></form>```

Comment: check https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L180 and just use the HTML code directly rather than calling the function

Comment: ah yep, that's the issue.  I forgot about the theme's searchform.php and I also forgot to turn WP_Debug on and now I'm seeing the error  `<Fatal error:  Call to undefined function twentyseventeen_get_svg()`

Comment: there you go, lol

Comment: if you make your comment into an Answer I can mark it as the accepted answer

Comment: yeah, I made one comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `get_search_form()` and not the sidebar, did you create `searchform.php` as part of your theme or you rely on the native wordpress form? you better use a plain html as your search form e.g.

```
<form action="/" method="GET"> <input type="text" name="s"><input type="submit" value="Search"></form>
```